# Pass list in Formdata from ajax call to controller

Tags: c#

I need to pass image and list of objects in formdata. how can i add it in formdata?
This is my function where i need to pass the formdata.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UploadBikeDetails(UploadBikeVM uploadedBike)
  {
  }
```

This is my UploadBikeVM model

```
   public class UploadBikeVM
   {
       public Bike Bike { get; set; }

       public List<Rent> Rent { get; set; }
   }
```

Lets says Rent class have Id and Name as fields, How can i add the list into formData?\

```
var formData = new FormData();
$('.BikeInfo select').each(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    formData.append(item.attr('name'), item.val());
});
formData.append('Bike.Rent', $scope.RentTypes);
```

I am doing an ajax call from which i need to send a list of type rent and 2 images uploaded in input type='file'

Comment: Please provide a bit more information on what you plan to do in the future. If you for indtsance just want to react on the post-button from an MVC-form you don't have to do anything because of Model Binding which is available in modern ASP.NET without MVC too. The ASP.NET runtime will perform the binding for you.

Comment: @sprinter252 : I am doing an ajax call from which i need to send a list of type rent and 2 images uploaded in input type='file'